# Write a query in MongoDB's client pymongo that converts a part of the string to a date on the fly

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So basically I have this collection where objects are stored with a string parameter.
example:

> {"string_": "MSWCHI20160501"}

The last part of that string is a date, so my question is this: Is there a way of writing a mongo query which will take that string, convert part of it into an IsoDate object and then filter objects by that IsoDate.

p.s 
I know I can do a migration but I wonder if I can achieve that without one.

Comment: Do your strings have the same length?

Comment: Beside the question asked by @user3100115 is the date format year-month-day (from the ambiguous example you posted it can also be year-day-month)?

Comment: @user3100115, well no, there are 2 types of those strings: with the length from example and twice that length.

Comment: @joao, Date format is always year-month-day.

Comment: is there any standard delimiter between the text part and the date part?

Comment: @lesingerouge, nope, it is a legacy string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the schema of your objects, you could hypothetically write an aggregation pipeline that would first transform the objects, then filter the results based on the results and then return those filtered results.

The main reason I would not recommend this way though is that, given a fairly large size for your dataset, the aggregation is going to fail because of memory problems.

And that is without mentioning the long execution time for this command.

Comment: So basically first loading everything in the dataset to memory, then make required transformation to date objects and then filter the results. Well thanks, i guess migration is the only way.

Comment: @Dan, it's probably the safest and fastest way around, unless you want to fiddle with Mongodb's settings or write javascript functions for this query.